# Which place to pick up for saving the output after creating release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have created 1 SQL database and 2 app service from azure, and then I started creating release pipeline but I am not sure what should I give in the boxes below after clicking on save button, can u please suggest what exactly and where I need to save and which path I should provide?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can group your release pipelines in folders for organisation purposes. It serves no other purpose than that. You can simply save it in the root folder `\`.

See example below putting a release pipeline in a folder:
[image: Release Pipeline Folders]